# Cross Compiling libcurl for arm-linux-gnueabihf: Unable to link function recv

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, libcurl, autoconf

I'm trying to cross-compile libcurl (version 7.54.0) for arm-linux-gnueabihf, I have the toolkit installed in my `$PATH`. I'm running the command to configure libcurl:

```
./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

> It starts configuring but then outputs: checking if sig_atomic_t is
>   already defined as volatile... yes checking return type of signal
>   handlers... void checking for sys/select.h... (cached) yes checking
>   for sys/socket.h... (cached) yes checking for select... no checking
>   for sys/types.h... (cached) yes checking for sys/socket.h... (cached)
>   yes checking for recv... no configure: error: Unable to link function
>   recv

I believe it may have something to do with the shared libraries, I installed `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` via `sudo apt-get install arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`

Comment: Had the same issue with curl 7.54 and arm-linux-gnueabi on Ubuntu. Downloaded 7.47 and ./configure executes just fine.

Comment: Has the same problem... tried both curl 7.60 and 7.47.0 - didn't work

Answer (score 2):

The function recv is the first to be check in terms of execution and linking by autotools. The standard flags for the test comprehend also -lz , which is the flag to link the zlib ( see the file config.log below ) :

```
 configure:21072: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.9 -o conftest -O2 -Wno-error -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-system-headers -O2 -Wno-error        conftest.c -lbrotlidec   -lz  >&5
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lbrotlidec
 /lib/../lib/libz.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

If you are cross compiling, the system location - generally /lib/libz.so - is not good. Please ensure to place the correct location of zlib using --with-zlib .

Answer (score -1):

[
i used, sudo ./configure ....
to pass the error point - Unable to link function recv
and need to use, sudo make
] ==>　sorry , this sould be wrong answer.

you shud 
export CPPFLAGS="-I...../include" ==> this is refer to ur target tool chain's include path.

refer to https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html